# Check for NULL ggplot object before adding layers in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have template plot functions that check whether a data frame has > 0 rows before running:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_fun <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) > 0) {
    df %>%
      ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  } 
}
```

Then I use this within pipes and add bespoke layers:

```
iris %>% plot_fun() + ggtitle("Plot me")
```

[image]

However if the data framed piped in has 0 rows I get an error because I am trying to add layers to nothing:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>% 
  plot_fun() +
  ggtitle("Plot me")
```

> Error in iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>% plot_fun() +
>   ggtitle("Plot me") :    non-numeric argument to binary operator

I can build a check mid pipe to avoid the error:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>%
  plot_fun() %>%
  {
    if (!is.null(.)) {
      . +
        ggtitle("Plot me")
    }
  }
```

That works but that seems clunky. Is it possible to make a function `check_df_pipe()` or something to stop the pipe if preceding filters remove all data? Or maybe to check if the pipe `.` is `NULL` at a point?

```
check_df_pipe <- function(x) {
  if(nrow(x) > 0) {
    x 
  } else{
    stop("Dont return an error just to exit pipe")
  }
}

iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>%
  check_df_pipe() %>% 
  plot_fun() +
  ggtitle("Plot me")
```

> Error in check_df_pipe(.) : Dont return an error just to exit pipe

Or any other ideas on how to deal with this? I don't want to add `ggtitle("Plot me")` into `plot_fun` because I wan't `plot_fun` to stay generic.

Comment: I assume your real use case is more involved than just adding a title? What are you really trying to do here? The act of piping just takes the output of one function and places it into the input of another. As such, it's not really possible to return early from a pipe. Typically you just make sure your functions are defensive against possible input. Is there a reason you are trying to put all this conditional logic into a single pipe?

Comment: I have some functions that provide a "base" plot which I then build upon variably. One situation is passing in a data frame which might have 0 rows after filtering. The filtering comes before the plotting so I need to check the state of play before adding additional layers. The answer below works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1: Blank plot

This doesn't directly answer your question, but how about a different approach?  When the dataframe has zero rows, use `geom_blank()` to create an empty plot.  Adding a title later doesn't return an error.

```
plot_fun <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) > 0) {
    df %>%
      ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  } else {
    ggplot(data = data.frame()) +
      geom_blank()
  }
}

iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>% 
  plot_fun() +
  ggtitle("Plot me")
```

## Option 2: Pass layers into a function

You can pass layers as function arguments.  Here's a function that checks whether the plot exists, and then adds the layers only if it does.

```
append_layers_maybe <- function(p, l) {
  if(!is.null(p)) {
    p + l
  }
}

iris %>%
  plot_fun() %>%
  append_layers_maybe(facet_wrap(~ Species)) %>%
  append_layers_maybe(ggtitle("Foo"))

iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>%
  plot_fun() %>%
  append_layers_maybe(facet_wrap(~ Species)) %>%
  append_layers_maybe(ggtitle("Plot me"))
```

Comment: I like this but it does return a blank plot. Ideally it would return nothing in case of using inside .Rmd reports.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.  What kinds of layers do you need to add?  Is it always `ggtitle`, or are you adding other kinds of layers?

Comment: It could be anything `ggplot` ish. Typically though it's `facet_wrap`, or `scale_*`. Sometimes whole additional geoms.

Comment: Happy for the answer to be: "just break up the pipe" if that is the best way. Just a nice to have.

Comment: Actually, I think it can be done (and it was easier than I expected!).  Edited the post; see if that meets your needs.

Comment: Works nicely thank you. Perhaps I should change the question title because it's not really the answer to the question but it is what I needed.

Comment: Your answer also works as `append_layers_maybe(list(addition1, addition2))` which means there is no need to call the function twice (you probably know that).

Comment: Nice!  I figured there was probably some kind of shortcut like that, but I was too lazy to check.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend such piping. It can be confusing to decode such a code. But here is a solution:

```
cond_pipe <- function(x) {
  if (nrow(x) > 0) {
    x %>%
      plot_fun() +
      ggtitle("Plot me")
  } else {
    warning("Dont return an error just to exit pipe")
  }
}

iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 1000) %>%
  cond_pipe()
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. Maybe you are right and I should just break up the pipe. You're solution works but I's like to keep the extra plot layers outside of `cond_pipe` otherwise I'd need many functions depending on what I want to add.